# How to handle runtime request value change in JMeter which is generated in results?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my project application, after login dashboard can be seen in which there is a Projects section where we can see a sequence of projects with an edit icon to open it. I'm recording a scenario where after login I'm opening the project record and then entering details in the second tab.

TransactionController1 for Login: There is 2 step authentication for login where I used regex

Result1: Passed with 2 requests.

TransactionController2 for Open project, Redirect and Save data in second tab:  Now when I open the record, it redirects me to a new page with many tabs where default focus is on the first tab and then I click on the second tab where I have to enter all details and save. 3 requests are generated: 1 for opening the project, 2nd for redirecting to 2nd tab, 3rd for saving details.

Result2: When I run this, the results show me an error like this "Oops! It seems some error has occurred. Sorry for the inconvenience. Click Here to go back to Home page" for the navigated page of first request, but the details entered for the second request second tab is executed properly as the data is reflected in the front end in the second tab of the project after execution. Again the same error is displayed for the 3rd request. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: HTML response error][image: request generated at run time]

Note: I'm verifying the HTML response in results mostly.

I hope you understand the scenario and request you to provide a solution for the above issue. The request link is generated at run time when we open the record but can't be seen in the response body.
Also I was unable to record this with JMeter so I used Blazemeter.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your request is failing due to missing or improperly implemented correlation of the `request` parameter, if the recorded hard-coded value doesn't work then you need to determine how the value is being generated, the options are in:

1. The value is present in response somewhere (pay attention to [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) as well), if you're being redirected most probably it's in [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header
2. The value can be encoded in something simple like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), if this is the case you will be able to use [custom JMeter Functions for encoding/decoding](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin)
3. The value can be encoded using one-way hash function, in this case you can use [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest)
4. In all other cases you should be able to use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to replicate client-side JavaScript logic which generates the `request` parameter

Comment: thanks.
I have checked for location headers, pls see below data
1.1: 1st request: Location: /erfglobal/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/ERFGlobal/chf/coverpage.aspx

1.2: 1st request has: Location: /erfglobal/Error.aspx?request=qQ4JqXU/iqn1X...
3.1: 3rd request: Location: /erfglobal/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/ERFGlobal/chf/logframe.aspx
3.2: 3rd request: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /erfglobal/Error.aspx?request=qQ4JqXU/iqn1Xoi...

whereas the links shows "Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath" | ... added as it was too long

So could I use Location header or any other options?